# AbandonedMutexException and ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

The `WaitOne` method of the `Mutex` object can throw the `AbandonedMutexException`. Thus by waiting for the mutex I'm able to distinguish between *normal* and *abandoned* state.

Another way to waiting is to register a callback using the `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method. Within the callback (which is executing in another thread) I know that the mutex has been signaled (the callback is being invoked), I even know whether the waiting has been timed out, but there is no way to know whether the mutex has been *abandoned*.

Is it correct?